# Get current URL link with a bookmark/bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I have searched the web for ways to do such, But I've only seen `javascript:void(prompt("URL:", location.href))` while I need the full link displayed at once, so is it possible to maybe do it with an alert? Any help

Comment: Have you tried what you suggested? just change prompt to alert?

Comment: it works, but it does not display the link, only "URL:"

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
javascript:alert("URL:" + location.href)
```

I think the void() in your code is to make the browser not change the location. But I checked in Firefox and Chromium and the void() was not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it looks like you tried the following:

```
javascript:void(alert("URL:", location.href))
```

This will result in an alert with just "URL:" as you experienced.

`alert` only takes one argument (message), unlike `prompt` which has two (message, defaultValue)

So you can (if you want to) use the `void()` but as somega's answer shows you do not need to.